# JQuery in aspx not working by linking master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is my simple page to rearrange the two photos.

When I remove MasterPageFile at page decleration, and use html, form, body tags in aspx page itself, the code works. May I know some direction how can I get the jquery working with masterpage addition? THis is not related to rearranging images, but a simple jquery may not work when we add master page to the aspx to make it easy for understanding as I feel I complicated by providing the code. There is no code-behind as I want to try this by hardcoding the image url, later I want to map the url path from a database table.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #sortable {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 450px;
    }

        #sortable li {
            margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
            padding: 1px;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 90px;
            font-size: 4em;
            text-align: center;
        }
</style>
<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#sortable").sortable();
      $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  });
```

```
<div runat="server" id="divPhotosDisplay">
    <h4 class="page-header">Masonry with any kind of element</h4>
    <div class="row-masonry row-masonry-md-4 row-masonry-sm-2" runat="server">
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default"  runat="server">

                  <asp:Image runat="server" id="imgPhoto1" style="width:150px;height:150px" src="//a57.foxnews.com/images.foxnews.com/content/fox-news/lifestyle/2017/09/30/dunkin-donuts-shrinking-menu-to-improve-doughnut-mojo/_jcr_content/par/featured_image/media-0.img.jpg/931/524/1506797282060.jpg?ve=1&tl=1&text=big-top-image" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre"  />


            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" runat="server">

                  <asp:Image runat="server" id="imgPhoto2" style="width:150px;height:150px" src="https://krispykreme.com/SharedContent/User/97/972786a8-7d91-4d82-983e-6b67a4a93865.png.ashx?w=310&h=310&mode=max&quality=60&format=jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" />

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't see why your code shouldn't work here. Whether you render the page by asp.net or hard code does not matter as long as your JavaScript files are loaded in order. Try this:

**SiteDonor.Master**:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Donor.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <style type="text/css">
        /* Your style here */
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>; 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>;
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Your script here */
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Content.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Title="Donor Application" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteDonor.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Donor.aspx.cs" Inherits="Eggspecting.Application.Donor" %> 

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    Your page content goes here
</asp:Content>
```

### Updated Example

I copied your example and built a web form project locally, and it works.

**Site.Master**:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="ASP.NET_Test.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">  
<head runat="server">
    <!-- Meta-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Display as grid</title>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $("#sortable").sortable();
          $("#sortable").disableSelection();
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
          #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
          #sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
          #sortable li img {
              width: 100px;
          }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmDonor" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="divPhotosDisplay">
        <h4 class="page-header">Masonry with any kind of element</h4>
        <div class="row-masonry row-masonry-md-4 row-masonry-sm-2">
            <ul id="sortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">1                    
                    <img runat="server" id="imgPhoto1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b8/Dunkin%27_Donuts_logo.svg/1280px-Dunkin%27_Donuts_logo.svg.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre"  >                      
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOrder1" runat="server" />                   
                </li>
                <li class="ui-state-default">2                    
                    <img runat="server" id="imgPhoto2" src="https://www.dunkindonuts.com/content/dam/dd/img/heros-lifestyle/standard/hero-ddcard-lp-donuts-card-640x640.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" >
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOrder2" runat="server" />                   
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>   
</asp:Content>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: <style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Here is my page directive.

<%@ Page Title="Donor Application" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteDonor.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Donor.aspx.cs" Inherits="Eggspecting.Application.Donor" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

Comment: Can someone give me a small example how it works for me to replicate the same way? I'm running out of ideas. Add master page to aspx. Use JQuery and get it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you remove master page, by using html, body tags in content page, my code works. Can you suggest the solution after replicating the issue?

My Content Page:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ArrangeDivs4.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" Inherits="Site.Examples.ArrangeDivs4" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Display as grid</title>    
    <div runat="server" id="divPhotosDisplay">
        <h4 class="page-header">Masonry with any kind of element</h4>
        <div class="row-masonry row-masonry-md-4 row-masonry-sm-2">
            <ul id="sortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">1                    
                      <img runat="server" id="imgPhoto1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b8/Dunkin%27_Donuts_logo.svg/1280px-Dunkin%27_Donuts_logo.svg.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre"  >                      
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOrder1" runat="server" />                   
                </li>
                <li class="ui-state-default">2                    
                      <img runat="server" id="imgPhoto2" src="https://www.dunkindonuts.com/content/dam/dd/img/heros-lifestyle/standard/hero-ddcard-lp-donuts-card-640x640.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" >
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOrder2" runat="server" />                   
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>   
</asp:Content>

My Master page:

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.Master.cs" Inherits="WebSite.Site1Master" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<head runat="server">
    <!-- Meta-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      } );
     </script>
    <style type="text/css">
          #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
          #sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmDonor" runat="server">
    .....
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this way and it did not work, please see my response as per your direction.

Comment: Your code works on my settings. Do you see any errors or warning messages in your compiler? If you open up the developer's tool in the browser, is there any error messages when the page is rendered? Does your page look any different than when you build it entirely with html?

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few more CSS files and JS files in master page. I’ll remove those tomorrow and try to get it work. If this works for you, it should work for me. I’m struggling for couple of days on this issue and I can provide an update tomorrow. Thanks a bunch for the response.